# How to run & stop python script from another python script?

Tags: python

I want code like this:

```
if True:
    run('ABC.PY')
else:
    if ScriptRunning('ABC.PY):
       stop('ABC.PY')
    run('ABC.PY'):
```

Basically, I want to run a file, let's say `abc.py`, and based on some conditions. I want to stop it, and run it again from another python script. Is it possible?

I am using Windows.

Comment: what python version you use?

Comment: 3.7, and 2.7 , if you want, I can change versions.

Comment: Also, I have few scripts in Python 2.7 and few in Python 3.6. If I can make a single script to run both, that will be great. But I can also create two separate scripts for running Python 3.7 and 2.7 code.

Comment: If you know a solution, please tell me that. Don't worry about versions, I can manage it.

Comment: I forgot to tell you, I am using Windows.

Comment: Why you should do that?! I mean if you were going to run python script in any other languages it'll make sense but running python from python?! you can import any function or class from any other python file and run it in need.

Comment: Actually, I have few scripts that should run 24/7. But sometimes, they crash. I want them to start again, as soon as they crash. Is there any other easy way of doing it?

I made a CSV file, that contains information if a script crashed or not.

Comment: You can create a docker image of your scripts and use a docker management tool (in your choice) to manage it 24/7.

Comment: I am using Windows, can I use that in WIndows @HamidrezaAhmadi?

Comment: Docker is free to use. As I know docker itself can be installed in "pro" or "enterprise" version of windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use python [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) objects for running processes in a child process

So `run('ABC.PY')` would be `p = Popen("python 'ABC.PY'")`

`if ScriptRunning('ABC.PY)` would be `if p.poll() == None`

`stop('ABC.PY')` would be `p.kill()`

Comment: Input to Popen is an array. It would either be Popen(["python", "ABC.PY'"]) or Popen(["python ABC.PY"], shell=True)

Comment: Works perfectly, Just one addition. If I call two or more script, the output of all scripts gets printed in the same command prompt. Can we open a separate command prompt for each and every script, we run?

Comment: I think this will work. `Popen("python ABC.PY", creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`

Comment: Any disadvantage of the above line?

Comment: Hey, If the main script shuts down. Is there any way to shut down all the other subprocess?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic example for what you are trying to achieve

Please checkout subprocess.Popen docs to fine tune your logic for running the script

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import time


def run(script):
    scriptArgs = shlex.split(script)
    commandArgs = ["python"]
    commandArgs.extend(scriptArgs)
    procHandle = subprocess.Popen(commandArgs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return procHandle


def isScriptRunning(procHandle):
    return procHandle.poll() is None


def stopScript(procHandle):
    procHandle.terminate()
    time.sleep(5)
    # Forcefully terminate the script
    if isScriptRunning(procHandle):
        procHandle.kill()


def getOutput(procHandle):
    # stderr will be redirected to stdout due "stderr=subprocess.STDOUT" argument in Popen call
    stdout, _ = procHandle.communicate()
    returncode = procHandle.returncode
    return returncode, stdout

def main():
    procHandle = run("main.py --arg 123")
    time.sleep(5)
    isScriptRunning(procHandle)
    stopScript(procHandle)
    print getOutput(procHandle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

One thing that you should be aware about is stdout=subprocess.PIPE.
If your python script has a very large output, the pipes may overflow causing your script to block until .communicate is called over the handle.
To avoid this, pass a file handle to stdout, like this

```
fileHandle = open("main_output.txt", "w")
subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=fileHandle)
```

In this way, the output of the python process will be dumped into the file.(You will have to modily the getOutput() function too for this)

Comment: Hello, ROK's answer looks much simple. Does your program have any advanage over his? like Memory management, as you mentioned.

Comment: Both are same. If your .py scripts output spew is large, just calling .Popen() will not work. You will have to redirect the output into a file, or call communicate() over the fileHandle.

Comment: Yeah, my scripts output one line per second. I will run 4 scripts at once.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

process = None

def run_or_rerun(flag):
    global process
    if flag:
        assert(process is None)
        process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'ABC.PY'])
        process.wait() # must wait or caller will hang
    else:
        if process.poll() is None: # it is still running
            process.terminate() # terminate process
        process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'ABC.PY']) # rerun
        process.wait() # must wait or caller will hang
```